# Java data structure that can be indexed and holds two values

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, data-structures, hashmap

Developing a football/soccer application, however I need a data structure that can be indexed and holds two values. If it can also be sorted that would be great.  The two values are the players name and their ratings out of 10. e.g.

(John Smith, 9).

The problem with HashMaps is that, even though it will hold two values, the data itself is not indexed.

Thanks,

Comment: `List<SoccerPlayer>` where `SoccerPlayer` is a class with two of your properties?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem (what exactly do you mean with "indexed", accessible via index, i.e. "get the x-th player"?). How about a `List<Player>`?

Comment: Indexed as in each entry holds a position, starting from index 0. So I can loop over them or access them.

Comment: You can access all HashMap entries by iterating through them. Why do you want an index?

Comment: You can use sortedMap like treemap.
Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html Any specific reason you want to keep it indexed?

Answer (score 3):

### Using a `Map<String, Integer>`

A map that relates the player names with their values should do the job:

```java
// Initialize the player map
Map<String, Integer> players = new HashMap<>();
players.put("John", 2);
players.put("Paul", 8);
players.put("Andrew", 5);
```

```java
// Print all players sorted by name
players.entrySet().stream()
       .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

```java
// Print all players sorted by rating
players.entrySet().stream()
       .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

```java
// Find a player by name and print their details
System.out.println(players.get("Paul"));
```

However the map entries cannot be accessed via an index. Keep reading.

### Using a `List<Player>`

Alternatively you could define a class to represent a player:

```java
public class Player {

    private String name;
    private Integer rating;

    public Player(String name, Integer rating) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    // Getters, setters and toString() methods
}
```

Then you can have the following:

```java
// Initialize the player list
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
players.add(new Player("John", 2));
players.add(new Player("Paul", 8));
players.add(new Player("Andrew", 5));
```

```java
// Print all players sorted by name
players.stream()
       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Player::getName))
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

```java
// Print all players sorted by rating
players.stream()
       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Player::getRating))
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

```java
// Find a player by name and print their details
String filter = "Paul";
players.stream()
       .filter(player -> player.getName().equals(filter))
       .findFirst()
       .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

```java
// Find a player by index and print their details
System.out.println(players.get(0));
```

Comment: Nice answer, but can you explain why you chose Integer instead of int for the rating field? Is it a common coding standard to prefer objects to primitives, or is it because you envisage having a null rating?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Primitive types cannot be used in collections, such as `List`s or `Map`s. That's why we use a wrapper class such as `Integer` instead of the `int` primitive type. Wrapper classes also allow `null` values.

Comment: Sorry I was referring to the `private Integer rating;` field in class `Player`. Instances of class `Player` can be stored in collections even if it contains fields of primitive types.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I've misunderstood your first comment. Sorry for that. An `int` would work as well, no issues. I've used `Integer` because I'd assumed that the rating could be `null` :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll create a class with the players details - one question though: is it bad practice to have lots of classes e.g. if have 20 players that'll mean 20 more classes?

Comment: @M.Doe _"if have 20 players that'll mean 20 more classes"_ No. You'll have a single class and 20 instances of that class. For example, you'll have a class `Player` and you'll instantiate it 20 times, one time for each player: `new Player("Cristiano Ronaldo", 10)`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Define your own class, like so:

   ```
   class Player {
       String name;
       float rating;
       // Class methods
   }
   ```
2. Create a `List` of `Player`s in your main class:

   ```
   List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
3. Use a custom `Comparator` to sort:

   ```
   Comparator<Player> comparator = new Comparator<Player>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
           //Sorting logic
       }
   };

   players.sort(comparator);
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll create a class with the players details - one question though: is it bad practice to have lots of classes e.g. if have 20 players that'll mean 20 more classes?

Comment: No, 20 players mean 20 objects of a single class `Player`. 20 objects is pretty normal for most programs.